# Touchpad locked when I press the keyboard

Tags: keyboard, touchpad

I am a bit new to Ubuntu, and this is the first time I have used Linux on a laptop (My daily driver is an MX desktop). So my problem is when I press the keyboard my touchpad gets locked up. For example when I press [X] [U] [O] [A] [H] or other keys on my keyboard, my touchpad just locked up and is unable to move. As soon as I release the key I am pressing on my keyboard my touchpad can move again. I have tried updating my touchpad driver, and looked around here for a bit for answers but nothing seems to work. I have also browsed around in the settings but there is no option to turn this "feature" off. When I use a normal mouse however, this does not happen. What can I do about this?

Thank you for your time.

Edit: I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, with Gnome version 3.36.3 (packaged standard with Ubuntu 20.04.1 I think). Sorry for leaving this out. I am not sure if this is relevant, but the laptop in question is ACER Aspire E15 Start ES1-512-P1SM. I have looked around forums if it is a hardware problem, but it doesn't seem like it is (it used to run Windows 8.1, and I didn't run into this problem there, or at least I wasn't aware of it.)

Comment: This is a feature(?).  There used to be a setting to disable touchpad when typing, but just looked around and could not find it either.  Think it is only touchpad because it is easier to hit touchpad when typing than a mouse.  Edit your question with Ubuntu version and desktop(probably gnome) so others might help better.

Comment: Why would you want to use a touchpad while typing? The feature can be easily disabled.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer instead of posting the "fix" to the question. And this fix won't survive reboots.

Comment: Is there a way to keep these settings "permanent"?

Comment: Yes, there is. I will write an answer.

Comment: Does anyone know why the easy setting found in earier versions to disable/enable touchpad while typing has disappeared?

Answer (score 2):

To disable the "Disable While Typing Enabled" feature permamanently, run

```
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf
```

and add `Option "DisableWhileTyping" "False"` to the touchpad section like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
        Option "DisableWhileTyping" "False"
EndSection
```

Comment: Thank you :) I really appreciate that you helped me with this. Have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed + instructions on how to fix it: So I accidentally fixed my touchpad problem. I downloaded a software called "touchpad indicator", it didn't do much, other then tell me that the touchpad driver is called "libinput". So from there I found a website that instructed me on how to access the driver properties/settings and how to change them. I wrote down a list on how to fix this problem if anyone else has it.

1. Open the terminal, and type `xinput --list` (xinput should come pre installed with ubuntu, but if it is not just type `sudo apt install xinput` )
2. You should get a list that looks a bit like this:

   ```
   ⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
   ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ⎜   ↳ ELAN0501:00 04F3:300B Mouse               id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ⎜   ↳ ELAN0501:00 04F3:300B Touchpad            id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
       ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard
   ```

So here (in my case) the "settings number" for my touchpad is "12" (it says in my case on the list ELAN0501:00 04F3:300B Touchpad id=12, so the "id=(X number)" is what you are looking for, my case it was "id=12")

3. After you have found out what your touchpad "id" is, type `xinput --list props 12` (<- the number should be the "id" number that you have, so not necessarily "props 12" but "xinput --list (your number)"
4. After that you should get a list displaying your settings. Here is a portion of what mine look like:

   ```
   libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (320):   0
   libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (321):   0
   libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (322):  1, 0
   libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (323):  1, 0
   libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (300):   1
   libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (301):   0
   libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (324):    1
   libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (325):    1
   libinput Scroll Methods Available (302):    1, 1, 0
   libinput Scroll Method Enabled (303):   1, 0, 0
   libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (304):   1, 0, 0
   ```

So here is what my settings for my touchpad looked like before I ""fixed"" the problem. There is a settings that is called:

"libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (325): 1"

To disable the setting just type:

`xinput set-prop 12 325 0` (<- again the touchpad setting id in my case was 12, but it may be a different number in your case)

And that should fix the problem, atleast it did in my case. Thank you so much for your help tough! I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to the above solution, which did not work for me.

After installing gnome-tweaks I was able to use the GUI to manually alter the setting Disable while typing.

1. Install gnome-tweaks with:

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
   ```
2. After installing, open gnome-tweaks by typing in your terminal:

   ```
   gnome-tweaks
   ```
3. Navigate to Keyboard and Mouse Tab.
4. Under Touchpad, unselect option Disable While Typing.

Hope this helps!

Courtesy of [this Unix & Linux question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/669565/cannot-use-trackpad-and-keyboard-at-the-same-time)